# Максимальное и минимальное значение элемента в масиве

Tags: c

> Написать функцию:
>
> - int arrayMin(int array[], int size).
>   Вернуть значение минимального элемента в массиве.
> - int arrayMax(int array[], int size).
>   Вернуть значение максимального элемента в массиве.

```
int arrayMin(int array[], int size) {
int min = array[0];

for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    if ( array[i] < min ) {
        min = array[i];
    }
}
return min;    
}

int arrayMax(int array[], int size) {
int max = array[0];

for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    if ( array[i] > max ) {
        max = array[i];
    }
}
return max;
}
```

Где-то ошибаюсь ?

Comment: Вот тоже самое, но чуть поизящнее: http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-говоря, если переданный размер массива некорректен *(т.е равен 0 или меньше нуля)*, то и программа некорректна. Ну и итерацию по массиву можно автоматически начинать с индекса 1, а не 0.

*Я бы предпочел для такой функции прототип `int arrayMax(int array[], unsigned int size)`
и дальше сделал бы проверку `if (size == 0) { ... }`.*

**Но вообще да, за исключением этих пунктов все правильно.**

Comment: Спасибо вы правы! )

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще интересный вариант попался:

```
function sortNumber(a,b)
{
    return a - b;  //в обратную сторону return b - a;
}

var n = ["10", "5", "40", "25", "100", "1"];
document.write(n.sort(sortNumber));
```